# How to get when user change the screen resolution in Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, desktop

I can get screens resolution when my application starts, but can I know when the user has changed the resolution?

Something like a event (example):

```
Screen.mainScreen.addEventListener("CHANGE_RESOLUTION", ...)
```

I've tried using a `setInterval` to monitor the resolution, but is this the best way to do this?

```
var resolution:Rectangle = Screen.mainScreen.bounds;

setInterval(function():void {

    if(!Screen.mainScreen.bounds.equals(resolution)) {
        trace("changed!");
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: I'd not use nameless closure and I would use **Event.ENTER_FRAME** rather than **setInterval**, but otherwise your code is fine. It doesn't seem that **Screen** supports any type of relevant events. So you are doing fine.

Comment: I agree, your code is fine.  If you want the fastest response to the resolution change, then yes, follow @Organis suggestion of an ENTER_FRAME handler instead of an interval.  However, there may be a performance cost to running that check every frame tick of your application and you may find using an interval to be better for your needs.   Test it out and do whatever you think works best!

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I doubt it is a weighty operation (although should be tested, ofc) so calling it 30-60 times a second probably won't hurt, while the response is the fastest this way.

Comment: @Organis - I imagine you're right, especially on desktop, but it's always good to point out potential bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, polling (what you're currently doing) is the only way in AS3 to detect screen resolution changes.

However, if you are in a **maximized or fullscreen** window, the window (or stage if set to NO_SCALE) will fire a **resize event** on a resolution change.  ([see the answer from Diniden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47518939/1457439)).  Though I'd recommend listening on the `stage.nativeWindow` object instead of stage itself.

> I'd say that you are doing it a perfectly acceptable way currently.

Keep in mind though, that if this is a desktop application, the user could have your program on a monitor that is not the primary one (`Screen.mainScreen`).  To support that scenario, you'd want to do something like the following:

```
//a constant to use for a custom event
const RESOLUTION_CHANGE:String = "resolution_change";

var resolution:Rectangle = curScreen.bounds;

//Adobe recommends using timers instead of setInterval - using ENTER_FRAME may be too expensive for your needs, but would afford the quickest reaction time.
var resolutionTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000); //poll every second (adjust to optimum performance for your application)
resolutionTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, pollScreenResolution);
resolutionTimer.start();

//get the screen that the window is on
function get curScreen():Screen {
    //get the first screen [0] that the current window is on
    return Screen.getScreensForRectangle(stage.nativeWindow.bounds)[0];
}

function pollScreenResolution(e:TimerEvent) {
    if(!curScreen.bounds.equals(resolution)) {
        trace("changed!");
        //dispatch our custom event
        stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(RESOLUTION_CHANGE));
        resolution = curScreen.bounds; //set the resolution to the new resolution so the event only dispatches once.
    }

}
```

Now you can listen for that event in other parts of your application.

```
stage.addEventListener(MovieClip(root).RESOLUTION_CHANGE, doSomething);
```

Comment: Thanks BadFeelingAboutThis!... But I think the `dispatchEvent` needs to be after `resolution = curScreen.bounds`, right? However, I was thinking that and I do something like this with an object. Thank's again!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle window resize events. You look at the stage of the given window for seeing how it's being resized. The other properties is to make it resize in a sensible way.

```
this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, stageResized);
```

Comment: Oh, Dinni, hi dear. Nice to know you're still out there. BTW, OP didn't mean the **Stage** resize, it's screen resolution change while your desktop AIR app might or might not be in the fullscreen mode.

Comment: This is a useful answer (+1), but only applicable if the application is maiximized or in fullscreen mode.  Also, since the question is tagged with AIR, it would be more appropriate to listen on `stage.nativeWindow`, as then the scaleMode can be anything and you'll still get the resize event.